# How to make tight bounding boxes respect an invisible artist?

Tags: matplotlib, bounding-box

I want to export a figure whose bounding boxes should be tight, but accounting for an artist that is invisible.
(I want to unveil that artist in a later variant of the plot, which shall have the same bounding boxes.)

My approach to this is:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.plot([0,1])
title = plt.title("my invisible title")
title.set_visible(False)
plt.savefig(
        "invisible_artist.png",
        bbox_inches="tight", pad_inches=0,
        bbox_extra_artists=[title],
        facecolor="grey", # just to visualise the bbox
    )
```

This produces:

[image: output of above script]

For comparison, here is the output with the title left visible, which is what I would expect in this case:

[image: output with visible title]

Obviously, when the title is made invisible, no space is left for it, while additional space is added in other directions.

Why does this happen and how can I achieve the desired result, i.e., have the same bounding box in both cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invisible artists are not taken into account for tight bbox calculations. Some workaround could be to make the title transparent,

```
title.set_alpha(0)
```

Or to use a whitespace as title

```
plt.title(" ")
```

More generally, you can of course get the tight bounding box *before* making the title invisible, then turn the title invisible and finally save the figure with the previously stored bbox.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([0,1])
title = ax.set_title("my invisible title")

bbox = fig.get_tightbbox(fig.canvas.get_renderer())
title.set_visible(False)

plt.savefig(
        "invisible_artist.png",
        bbox_inches=bbox,
        facecolor="grey", # just to visualise the bbox
    )

plt.show()
```

[image]

The drawback is that `pad_inches` only works for `bbox_inches="tight"`. So to achieve the effect of `pad_inches` for such manually specified bbox one would need to manipulate the `Bbox` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the color of the title to be the same as the `facecolor`, i.e., `'grey'` in your case. Now you don't need `title.set_visible(False)`. I make it more general by using a variable `col` to specify the color

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

col = 'grey'
plt.plot([0,1])
title = plt.title("my invisible title", color=col)
plt.savefig(
        "invisible_artist.png",
        bbox_inches="tight", pad_inches=0,
        bbox_extra_artists=[title],
        facecolor=col, # just to visualise the bbox
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I would consider this at best a makeshift workaround. Also, it has several problems such as not translating to more complex artists (e.g., legends) and inhomogeneous backgrounds as well as adding the necessity of keeping track of that colour.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: My aim here was to address the question you asked without providing a general solution. This is indeed a workaround for what you asked. Regarding keeping track of the color, you anyway are specifying explicitly the facecolor. You can in that case use a variable `col='grey'` and then use it in both the commands.